# Catch error when querying with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, try-catch

I have a portion of code importing .sql files to execute this way:

```
<?php
$Server = "localhost";
$Db     = "test";
$User   = "root";
$Pass   = "";

function exec_file($File_Path) {
  global $Server,$Db,$User,$Pass;  

  $Con = new PDO("mysql:host=$Server;dbname=$Db",$User,$Pass);
  $Con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  try {
    $Sql = file_get_contents($File_Path);
    $Res = $Con->exec($Sql);
  }
  catch (PDOException $Ex) {
    echo $Ex->getMessage();
  }
}
```

The .sql file contain multiple SQL commands. All these commands are executed well, however, **when having error in these commands, the 'catch' block can catch only error in the first command in .sql file**.

There should be some way to catch error in the second command onward?

Comment: That's because you're trying to execute a whole file as 1 query so it will stop executing when it reaches the first error. What you could do is use transaction and execute each line instead of the entire file so you can catch all the errors and then commit it.

Comment: how to break sql text into sql statements to exec 1 by 1?

Comment: Well one way would be initiating the trasaction then breaking down the queries on your file and do a `foreach` to execute each of it. With the transaction it won't take as long to execute em.

Comment: Maybe you could explode the file on the semicolons ";" and then loop trough the array you get.

Comment: 'explode' is crazy, row data contain these semicolons also